# Allow trait object creation with user-defined type?

Tags: rust, traits

In Rust, references as well as `Box<T>`, `Rc<T>`, and `Arc<T>` allow the creation of a trait object (e.g., from `Box<Type>` to `Box<dyn Trait>`). But is there a way to allow the same conversion with a user-defined generic "smart pointer" type?

For example, `MyBox<T>` is a thin wrapper around `Box<T>` but the code below results in a compilation error:

```rust
use std::io::Write;

pub fn main() {
    let std_box: Box<Vec<u8>> = Box::new(Vec::new());
    let std_dyn: Box<dyn Write> = std_box;
    // ^ this conversion is allowed.

    let my_box: MyBox<Vec<u8>> = MyBox { t: Box::new(Vec::new()) };
    let my_dyn: MyBox<dyn Write> = my_box;
    // ^ this conversion is not allowed.
}

struct MyBox<T: ?Sized> {
    t: Box<T>,
}
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> traits/src/trait_objs.rs:7:36
  |
7 |     let my_dyn: MyBox<dyn Write> = my_box;
  |                 ----------------   ^^^^^^ expected trait object `dyn std::io::Write`, found struct `Vec`
  |                 |
  |                 expected due to this
  |
  = note: expected struct `MyBox<dyn std::io::Write>`
             found struct `MyBox<Vec<u8>>`
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, it looks like the answer is "you don't" for Rust Stable. Rust is very conservative in which implicit coercions it allows. In particular, from [the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html#coercion-types), we see the rule that's kicking in for `Box`.

> Coercion is allowed between the following types:
>
> ...
>
> - TyCtor(`T`) to TyCtor(`U`), where TyCtor(`T`) is one of
>
>   - `&T`
>   - `&mut T`
>   - `*const T`
>   - `*mut T`
>   - `Box<T>`
>
> and where `U` can be obtained from `T` by [unsized coercion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html#unsized-coercions).

where the relevant unsized coercion rule is

> - `T` to `dyn U`, when `T` implements `U + Sized`, and `U` is [object safe](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety).

There's not much room for special casing there, at least not in the current version of Rust.

*However,* if you're willing to dip into Nightly-only features, then you get the exciting [`CoerceUnsized` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.CoerceUnsized.html), whose intended use case is... smart pointers to things which would coerce like a `Box` would.

```
#![feature(unsize, coerce_unsized)]

use std::ops::CoerceUnsized;
use std::marker::Unsize;

impl<T, U> CoerceUnsized<MyBox<U>> for MyBox<T> where T: Unsize<U>, U: ?Sized {}
```

This tells Rust we can coerce `MyBox<T>` to `MyBox<U>` if `T` is "basically the same" as `U`, for an appropriate definition of "basically the same". No functions are required on the implementation; the trait `impl` simply needs to exist.